# Using the same button in different Tkinter frames

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I'm currently working on a simple GUI written using the Tkinter library for Python that makes use of two different frames. With a button I can switch between the two frames making only one of the two visible at a time.

There's one specific button that I would require to use in both frames. Is it possible to place it in different frames?

Of course I have several back-door solutions to my problem, like creating a button that makes use of the same variables and commands, but what I would like to know is if it is possible to use exactly the same button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place a button in whatever frame you want (with the exception you can't move a widget between toplevel windows). However, the button can't appear in two frames at the same time.

It's certainly possible to move the button when you switch frames, though I would either move the button to a common toolbar, or just have two buttons that call the same functions. Moving the button around adds complexity without giving much extra value in return.